# Do "pure Spring" based servlets have Endpoint URL like CXF based WSDL have?

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I have a perfectly working demo server/client apps pair using Spring (only!) -- no CXF or WSDL involved. It runs with the help of Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.

I was curious to see whether I can see any trace to its presence on a browser (`http://localhost:8080/`) but I couldn't find any hint to a URL in the source code (copied verbatim from a tutorial).

I then found [this thread](http://www.java.net/node/701934) which provided a way to get the endpoint's URL:

```
TransportContext tc = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
WebServiceConnection wc = tc.getConnection();
URI uri = wc.getUri();
```

I added this to my demo/tutorial *client's* code and while the first statement (`getTransportContext()`) doesn't throw any exception, it **returns null** and so the second one (`getConnection()`) throws a NullPointerException .

Why?

Do "pure" Spring based servlets lack endpoint URLs?

If not, what am I missing? What is the way to retrieve the service's URL?

I know that the client knows about the server by means of the *context path* and the *bean id* (as defined in the shared *beans.xml*):

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] {"/sample/spring/beans.xml" } );
```

But isn't there a URL equivalent to this? Like WSDLs do?

Comment: No - a servlet is not a webservice - the concept of an 'endpoint' doesn't exist there. It's just going to be a straightforward HTTP (or HTTPS) url. There's no standard as to how the client resolves that url - if you don't know where it's configured, you're going to have dig into the source code to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @GreyBeardedGeek's comment, there's no concept of endpoint URL on Spring web-app (java servlet web-app in general).

If you do need to runtime lookup what URL the user used to reach your app, you can use ServletRequest / HttpServletRequest methods such as getRemoteAddr(), getRemoteHost(), getURL(), getContextPath() etc. Eg:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home(HttpServletRequest req) {
  String host =  req.getRemoteHost();
  // ...
}
```

However keep in mind multiple URL can point to the same tomcat server, eg if a reverse proxy / DNS CName is setup. And that might (or not) yield different URL for you.